# Calculate the taxable % for each employee using sql developer between two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, inner-join

I need to design a sql developer query in such a way to get the desired output table using table1 and table2.

**Table1:** Employee Table as per the below image
https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4oyj.png

**Table2:** Tax Slab Table as per the below image
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBZ3b.png

Display the **Tax_Percentage value in Table2** against the **Emp ID and Salary Range in Table1**

**Need the out as per this Output table** - 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOVNu.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join with inequality conditions:

```
select e.empid, e.salary, t.tax_percentage
from employee e
inner join tax t on e.salary >= t.start_range and e.salary < t.end_rage
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know if it suits your purpose.

```
SELECT  emp_id,  salary,  tax_percentage 
FROM  table1,  table2 
WHERE  salary  BETWEEN  table1.start_range  AND table2.end_range 
ORDER BY. emp_id
```